# Reset random number seed for sequence modeling (LSTM) in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, random-seed

I'm using LSTM for forecasting a time series. So In every step, I train the model using 1000 samples and apply the trained model on the next sample. I do this rolling window strategy to forecast the next 100 samples using the trained model. Should I reset the Random Number Seed (set it to the initial seed when we open Spyder) every time I want to train the model? If yes, why and how can I do that in Keras?

Comment: What do you mean by "step"? do you mean iteration?

Comment: No, This is one step ahead forecasting. So we have something like this: training using `1:1000` samples, forecasting `1001`. The next one: training with `2:1001`, forecasting `1002`.

Comment: humm. If I get you right, if all of your time series is list `L`, then your "(X,Y)" is `[(L[0:1000] ,L[1001]), (L[1:1001] ,L[1002]), (L[2:1002] ,L[1003]) ......]`. Am I right?

Comment: @Peyman Yes. That's correct.

Comment: Good news: no need to change the seed. just feed the data to Keras and it will handle it. `BAD NEWS:` RNNs are not good in a very long time series (like 1000). they will forget the old ones, they are not that good to handle this long.

Comment: For what purpose do you seek to reset the seed? Also, by "1000 samples" do you mean 1000 sequences, or one sequence with 1000 timesteps?